# Group or chunk array with maximum sum limit

Tags: javascript, algorithm, group-by, reduce, chunks

I have an array like this

```
const array = [{id: 1, size: 1}, {id: 2, size: 2}, {id: 3, size: 4}, {id: 4, size: 1}, {id: 5, size: 2}, {id: 6, size: 3}, ...]
```

I want to group or chunk this array with the maximum sum of size properties (the sum size of every indexes cannot be greater than `4`),

so new array should be something like this:

```
  const newArray = [
    [{id:1, size: 1}, {id:2, size: 2}, {id:4, size: 1}],
    [{id:3, size: 4}],
    [{id:5, size: 3}],
    [{id:6, size: 4}],
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: Can you please share your code if you have made any attempts?

Comment: You don't specify whether size of individual elements can ever exceed 4 (and how to handle that situation if it's feasible). You also don't say whether order matters for the chunking.  I.e., if a series of elements has sizes `1, 4, 3`, a "smart" algorithm might try to chunk the `1` and the `3` together, but they are not consecutive, so if order matters, that's relevant.  You should really try to provide all requirements in your original post to eliminate back & forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the next slot by looking to the sum of each slot.

```js
let array = [{ id: 1, size: 1 }, { id: 2, size: 2 }, { id: 3, size: 4 }, { id: 4, size: 1 }, { id: 5, size: 2 }, { id: 6, size: 3 }],
    sum = 4,
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        const temp = r.find(a => a.reduce((s, { size }) => s + size, 0) + o.size <= sum);
        if (temp) temp.push(o);
        else r.push([o]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

my way...

```js
const array = 
      [ { id: 1, size: 1 } 
      , { id: 2, size: 2 } 
      , { id: 3, size: 4 } 
      , { id: 4, size: 1 } 
      , { id: 5, size: 2 } 
      , { id: 6, size: 3 } 
    //  , ...
      ]
  , szMax  = array.reduce((t,c)=>Math.max(t,c.size),0)
  , temp   = array.map(e=>({...e}))
  , result = []
  ;
while (temp.length > 0)
  {
  let sz = szMax
    , nv = []
    ;
  while( sz > 0 )
    {
    let idx = temp.findIndex(x=>x.size <= sz)
    if (idx===-1) break
    nv.push( temp[idx] )
    sz -= temp[idx].size
    temp.splice(idx,1)
    }
  result.push([...nv])
  nv = []
  }

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top: 0;}
```